# Direct formula for 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4,...

Tags: functions

Is it possible to create a function which takes on the values $$1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5...$$ for the inputs
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...$$
?

It would be nice to have a direct formula instead of a generating function, which wolfram alpha allready gave me.

Comment: This sequence is https://oeis.org/A001057; see that page for much more information, including formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. $f(x) = (-1)^{x+1} \left\lceil\frac{x}{2} \right\rceil$ should work.

Comment: $f(2) = 1$. Yet here we need $f(2) = -1$.

Comment: @amWhy yes, I realized and edited about 10 seconds after submitting. Perhaps it is not showing up yet.

Comment: Refreshed the page.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

If you sum two consecutive terms you find alternatively $0$ or $1$; so if you sum two consecutive terms and subtract the following two, you get $0$.

Thus the sequence satisfies the recurrence
$$
a_n+a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}-a_{n+3}=0
$$
This leads to the characteristic polynomial
$$
x^3+x^2-x-1
$$
that has roots $1$ and $-1$ (double), so the general solution is of the form
$$
a_n=p+q(-1)^n+r(-1)^nn
$$
and inserting the initial conditions $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$ and $a_3=2$ we obtain
\begin{cases}
p-q-r=1 \\[4px]
p+q+2r=-1 \\[4px]
p-q-3r=2
\end{cases}
so $p=1/4$, $q=-1/4$ and $r=-1/2$:
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{(-1)^n}{4}-\frac{(-1)^nn}{2}
$$
Note that $n=0$ gives also the expected $a_0=0$.